# Symfony3 form convert 0 to NULL value

Tags: symfony

I have problem with my Symfony3 form.
My ShippingType look like:

```
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('price', TextType::class, [
            'required'   => false,
            'empty_data'  => 0
        ])
        ->add('url')
        ->add('tax', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                '0%' => 0,
                '5%' => 5,
                '8%' => 8,
                '23%' => 23,
            ],
        ])
        ->add('free_delivery_level')
    ;

    $builder
        ->get('price')
        ->addModelTransformer($this->priceTransformerShipping);
```

Problem is when my shipping price is 0. Symfony still convert is to NULL value. When I dump form data I get results like this:

> object(AppBundle\Entity\Shipping)#8397 (6) { ["id":protected]=> NULL
>   ["name":protected]=> string(4) "asdg" ["price":protected]=> NULL
>   ["url":protected]=> NULL ["tax":protected]=> int(0)
>   ["free_delivery_level":protected]=> NULL }

I also try to change setPrice($price) to this:

```
public function setPrice($price)
{
    if(!$price){
        $price = 0;
    }

    $this->price = $price;
}
```

But it also not work

---

My Price transformer code:

```
class PriceTransformerShipping implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($price)
    {
        if(is_null($price)){
            return 0;
        }
        $price /= 100.0;

        return number_format($price, 2, ',', '');
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if(empty($value) || is_null($value)){
            return null;
        }
        $price = str_replace(',', '.', $value);

        return $price * 100;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's your mapping information for `$price` ?

Comment: You need to show us your transformer code too

Comment: I update code, thanks :)

Comment: I try to replace transform function by retrun $price and it also not work :/

Comment: You could declare the default value of the price property to 0 in your entity: `private $price = 0;`

Comment: It works ;) Thanks :)